# Need of 2 $ORIGIN Directives

Tags: dns, bind

In most of the DNS Zone examples, as below

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
example.com     IN SOA  dns.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
        2001062504 ; serial
        21600      ; refresh (6 hours)
        3600       ; retry (1 hour)
        604800     ; expire (1 week)
        86400      ; minimum (1 day)
        )
    NS  dns.example.com.
    A   192.168.1.2
    MX  10 mail.example.com.
 $ORIGIN example.com.
 $TTL 60 ; 1 minute
 dd2         A   192.168.1.7
 $TTL 86400  ; 1 day
 ex1         A   192.168.1.2
 ex2         A   192.168.1.2
 ex3         A   192.168.1.3
 ex4         A   192.168.1.4
```

I have seen ORIGIN used as $ORIGIN . and $ORIGIN example.com.

What is the use of this? Is this for Delegation within the same Zone file?

**UPDATE:**

I tried as below:

```
$ORIGIN lab.example.com.
$TTL 1d
@     IN      SOA     colombo root.lab.example.com.  (
                                      2003022720 ; Serial
                                      56800      ; Refresh
                                      14400      ; Retry
                                      3600000    ; Expire
                                      2h )    ; Min

;NS Records
@              IN      NS      ns1.lab.example.com.
@              IN      NS      ns2.lab.example.com.
mail           IN      NS      ns1.mail.lab.example.com

;A Records
ns1            IN      A       192.0.2.123
ns2            IN      A       192.0.2.124

$ORIGIN mail.lab.example.com.
ns1            IN      A       192.0.2.155
```

But when I do this

```
named-checkzone lab.example.com lab.example.zone
zone lab.example.com/IN: mail.lab.example.com/NS 'ns1.mail.lab.example.com.lab.example.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone lab.example.com/IN: loaded serial 2003022720
OK
```

Why do I get error Like?

```
zone lab.example.com/IN: mail.lab.example.com/NS 'ns1.mail.lab.example.com.lab.example.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
```

Comment: @grawity: Am i doing anything wrong

Comment: I think grawity won't be notified of your comment because he hasn't commented under the question. This is explained in the ["Replying in comments" section here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-reply). To get grawity's attention post a comment under *his* answer. Also: you have accepted an answer which means the (original) problem is resolved, but now you're expanding the question. This doesn't fit. Either the original problem is not really resolved or this update is a *new* problem that deserves a *separate* question. I know little about DNS but I suspect the latter.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for notifying. Proably I will post a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `$ORIGIN` is just a shortcut that sets the default "suffix" for all records which follow it. It is expanded when loading the zone file, and is not visible externally.

If a field contains a domain name *not* ending with `.`, then it's a *relative* domain name and will have the current origin appended to it. You can of course still use absolute domain names (ending with a dot) where necessary.

(So using `$ORIGIN .` just makes relative `example.com` and absolute `example.com.` equivalent.)

As an example, all of these snippets are equivalent:

1. No $ORIGIN at all:

   ```
   example.com.       MX     mail.example.com.
   www.example.com.   CNAME  mail.example.com.
   ftp.example.com.   CNAME  ftp.iana.org.
   mail.example.com.  A      1.2.3.4
   a.ns.example.com.  A      2.3.4.5
   ```
2. Single $ORIGIN:

   ```
   $ORIGIN example.com.
   @     MX     mail
   www   CNAME  mail
   ftp   CNAME  ftp.iana.org.
   mail  A      1.2.3.4
   a.ns  A      2.3.4.5
   ```
3. Multiple $ORIGIN:

   ```
   $ORIGIN example.com.
   @     MX     mail
   www   CNAME  mail
   ftp   CNAME  ftp.iana.org.
   mail  A      1.2.3.4
   $ORIGIN ns.example.com.
   a     A      2.3.4.5
   ```